# How to extract the domain in a string by using regex?

Tags: subdomain

I got a string representing users data.

What is the proper regex to extract domain in this string?

I know that I have to find all strings with 2 characters matching the condition that it comes after the last "." after a "@".

However I still failed to implement it.

Comment: Well, what is the rule that tells you that e.g. `uk` is a country domain and `com` isn't? What is the rule that tells you that `uk` and `com` are domains, and e.g. `co` and `ac` aren't? What concrete steps would you take in order to solve the problem with pencil and paper?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I misrepresented my question by the word "country domain". The purpose of my program just want to extract the two characters only, so the ```co``` or ```com``` are not included.

Comment: On SO we encourage showing what you have tried in the question. Can you update the question with your code or pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import re

regex = r"@.+\.([a-z]{2}),"

your_string = ("001,Francisca,Dr Jhonaci,jhonadr@abc.com,32yearsold,120.238.225.0\n"
    "002,Lavenda,Bocina,lavenboci@banck.ac.uk,50yearsold,121.186.221.182\n"
    "003,Laura,Eglington,elinton@python.co.jp,26yearsold,36.55.173.63\n"
    "004,Timo,Baum,timobaum@tennis.co.cn,22yearsold,121.121.110.10")

matches = re.finditer(regex, your_string, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    result = match.group(1)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma seems to be the delimiter in the string.

To not cross-matching a comma (to prevent matching too much), and also not cross-matching a second @ char you can use a negated character class starting with `[^`

If the entry can also be at the end of the string, you can assert either a `,` or the end of the string.

```
@[^@,]*\.([A-Za-z]{2})(?=,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYgMMl/1)

```
import re

regex = r"@[^@,]*\.([A-Za-z]{2})(?=,|$)"

s = ("001,Francisca,Dr Jhonaci,jhonadr@abc.com,32yearsold,120.238.225.0\n"
    "002,Lavenda,Bocina,lavenboci@banck.ac.uk,50yearsold,121.186.221.182\n"
    "003,Laura,Eglington,elinton@python.co.jp,26yearsold,36.55.173.63\n"
    "004,Timo,Baum,timobaum@tennis.co.cn,22yearsold,121.121.110.10")

print(re.findall(regex, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['uk', 'jp', 'cn']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the comma after the email instead of the last point.

Using this regex

```
@.+\.(\w+)(?<!com),
```

the capturing group will contain the info that you want.